# Is there a way to show the actual value of ggplotly histogram

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I have a plot:

[image: Plotly Histogram]

The value I'm hovering over is supposed to read `grade: 10`. The groups of G1, G2, G3 is all sharing the same value so I believe ggplot/plotly adds or subtracts 0.3 to the actual value due to spacing. Is there a way to fix this so it reads the actual correct value?

Here is the code:

```html
por = data %>% 
  gather(period, grade, G1:G3) %>% select(period, grade) %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_bar(aes(x=grade, fill=period), position="dodge", size=1)
  
ggplotly(por)
```

Comment: Please provide your plotting code and a reproducible sample of your data

Comment: added plot code